# check if interface{} is slice of something ([]interface{})

Tags: go

```
func main() {
    strSlice := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    f(strSlice)
}

func f(slice interface{}) {
    anySlice, isSlice := slice.([]interface{})
    fmt.Printf("isSlice = %t, anySlice = %#v\n", isSlice, anySlice)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/UN25mIOqmOd

This program prints `isSlice = false, anySlice = []interface {}(nil)`. Why is that?
I would have expected this type asssertion to be possible.

And: Is there a way to dynamically check that interface{} is a slice of something?

Answer (score 4):

The type assertion fails because a `[]string` is not an `[]interface{}`. See [the FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface) for details.

Use the [reflect package](https://godoc.org/reflect) to determine if the concrete value in an interface is a slice:

```
func f(slice interface{}) {
    isSlice := reflect.ValueOf(slice).Kind() == reflect.Slice
    fmt.Printf("isSlice = %t, anySlice = %#v\n", isSlice, slice)
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2goVt_a4Zs-).

You can also use the reflect package to iterate through the values:

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
isSlice := v.Kind() == reflect.Slice
if isSlice {
    for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d: %v\n", i, v.Index(i).Interface())
    }
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sOqEqbDIQID).

Answer (score 2):

> This program prints `isSlice = false, anySlice = []interface {}(nil)`. Why is that?

because `slice` doesn't contain a `[]interface{}`, it contains a `[]string`. Those are different types, and Go doesn't give you any notion of covariant container types.

> And: Is there a way to dynamically check that interface{} is a slice of something?

Yes, you can use reflection:

```
func f(slice interface{}) {
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(slice)
    if typ.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        elemType := typ.Elem()
        fmt.Println("slice of", elemType.Name())
    } else {
        fmt.Println("not a slice")
    }
}
```

Actually *doing* anything with that information may be more involved.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if you change your assertion to: `slice.([]string)` **things will work as expected**. This makes sense when you consider how Go handles `string` to `interface{}` type assertions. The following will result in a compilation error:

```
package main

func main() {
    s := "some string"
    i := s.(interface{})
}
```

Error:

```
invalid type assertion: s.(<inter>) (non-interface type string on left)
```

It makes sense that going from `[]string` to `[]interface{}` should also fail since Go does not treat strings as `interface{}` types.

Comment: Ok, that would work if the required slice needs to a string slice. I just need to know if it is a slice of anything. Later code checks the concrete types again. Usecase is from here: https://github.com/Ragnaroek/format where the user can input anything and the formatter acts on the concrete type.

Comment: Does it make sense to infer types from the format verb? For example, the `fmt` package uses `%s` for strings, `%d` for integers, `%t` for booleans, etc. I'm not super familiar with Lisp format verbs but does it make sense to take a similar approach?

Comment: Lisp has recursion format("list: ~{~a~,}", []string{"a", "b","c"}) which will print "list: a, b, c ". The content of the slice depends on the directives used inside the loop. I could infer that, but I just want to call format recursively, hence the need for "is it a []interface{}?". But for the other types you are right, the type is know and can be checked directly.